# GoogleMaps not found

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, google-maps, bridging-header

I am trying to use google maps in my ios app my Xcode ver is 7.2 and swift ver is 2.1.1. I simply add GoogleMaps in my pod file everything is fine i added frameworks and libs which are required to support Googlemaps all fine, i am following this [tut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial) and according to this i have to add a bridging header file to include 
`#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`. My app already have one bridging header file because i am using facebook login as well so i put the import statement in the same file and in 'others linker flag -ObjC' is already there so after few required settings in storyboard i compiled my proj but i am getting this error "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" not found. I have searched for it and tried almost all the suggested ways on Stackoverflow but hard luck nothing worked yet.I will be really grateful if anyone could suggest me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `pod install` went smoothly.

According to the tutorial,

> You should see output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Downloading dependencies
> Installing GoogleMaps (1.10.4)
> Using SwiftyJSON (2.3.0)
> Generating Pods project
> Integrating client project
> ```

Comment: I think you've got me, following is my result and there is no Using SwiftyJSON thing. How can i get that ?
Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleMaps (1.11.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

Comment: SwiftyJSON is another cocoapod - I doubt it's causing your issues, unless it's a hidden requirement for Google Maps (unlikely). You can add it to your podfile to make sure: [SwiftyJSON cocoapods instructions](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#cocoapods-ios-8-os-x-109)

Comment: Oh got that, than i think my installation is perfect!

Comment: I think the author of the tutorial is using SwiftyJSON for other things. Like I said, you can try adding it to your podfile using the link in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#import "GoogleMaps.h"
```

in your bridging header file